# In bash, cp does copy dot files while using wildcard? Which option should I use

Tags: bash, copy, wildcard

When I use 
    cp -r source dest, 
the dot files as in .gitIgnore or any .xyz are ignored. When I use 
    cp -r source/.xyz dest, 
then they are copied. Which option with cp can copy all the files including the dot files while using the wildcard *?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the wildcard like cp -r .[^.]*

Thats because your bash is built to ignore the hidden files and cp command just don't get the hidden arguments. Thats how its supposed to work .. :)

Comment: as in ```cp -r from/.[^.]* to/```

Answer (score 5):

As for me the most universal way:

```
cp -a /source/. /destination/
```

Or if you are inside of a source folder:

```
cp -a . /destination/
```

Answer (score 0):

While using a wildcard `*`, you can try the command `cp source/*.* destination/` to copy all the hidden files too.

If you want to include unhidden directories in the `cp` command you can try the below command

```
cp -r source/. destination/
```

Note the `.` at the end of source. That includes all the files and directories in the source including hidden ones.

Or

```
cp -r source/{.,}* destination/
```

`x{.,}y` is converted to `x.y` and `xy`. In your case it will be `source/.*` and `source/*`

Comment: Thanks! All your options worked except for the first one : `cp source/*.* destination/`. It didn't copy the dot files.